# What does this compiler build statement mean?

Tags: c++, build-process, build, build-error

I am a programming student in my second OOP class, which is taught in C++, and I am using Visual Studio 2008.

I keep encountering this weird statement when I build my project in VS, my project builds fine, I would just like to know what it means. It appears every time I build my project, doesn't matter if I click rebuild or what configuration I use.

Thanks!

The statement:

`LINK : C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Project_2\Debug\Project_2.exe not found or not built by the last incremental link; performing full link`

[The complete build log is here](http://www.myucas.com/BuildLog.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can safely ignore it.

Incremental linking speeds things up.  What happens is that rather then do a link from scratch, it uses the results of the last link to speed things up.

If it can't do an incremental link, it issues you that warning and does a full link.  All it means is that it will take longer to link.